# Finding median of values in one column given corresponding consecutive values in another column are equal numbers

Tags: r, median

I have a data frame that looks like this in R:

```
Date | Time | value  
A  | 1  | 3       
A  | 1  | 6     
A  | 2  | 4  
A  | 3  | 3  
A  | 4  | 2  
A  | 5  | 7  
B  | 1  | 6       
B  | 2  | 5  
B  | 2  | 3  
B  | 2  | 4  
B  | 3  | 2  
B  | 5  | 3  
B  | 6  | 4  
...
```

My aim is to find the median of the numbers in the third column if the numbers in the second columns are equal in consecutive rows. I.e take the median of the values if they occur at the same time, and replacing that median value for that corresponding time slot.

So output I am aiming for:

```
A  | 1  | median (3,6)       
A  | 2  | 4  
A  | 3  | 3  
A  | 4  | 2  
A  | 5  | 7  
B  | 1  | 6       
B  | 2  | median (3,4,5)   
B  | 3  | 2  
B  | 5  | 3  
B  | 6  | 4  
...
```

I am desperately trying to avoid loops since the data set is huge. The main problem I am having is collecting the values separately. This is what I had thus far:

```
#First find consecutive time slots that are equal:
timeslots_equal<-which(diff(data_RAW$TIME)==0)

coordinates_placesholder <- sort(c(as.vector(timestamp_equal_coordinates), as.vector(timestamp_equal_coordinates)+1))

coordinates_placesholder2  <-  coordinates_placesholder[-c(which(diff(coordinates_placesholder)==0), which(diff(coordinates_placesholder)==0) +1)]

 #The following matrix are the coordinates in the value vector with equal time slots
 matrix_ranges<-t(matrix(coordinates_placesholder2,2))
```

`matrix_ranges` for the example above would look like:

```
1 | 2  
8 | 10
```

Then I tried to apply something like

```
median(data_RAW$Value[matrix_ranges[,1]:matrix_ranges[,2]])
```

This did not work. Does anyone have any answers on doing this?

Also is there an easier way to doing this than what I did above?

Comment: Can we assume the data are sorted? If so, then can't you just use something like: `aggregate(value ~ Date + Time, mydf, median)`?

Comment: @user2868055, +1 to you for posting your first question with a small, reproducible example, the desired output, and that you show _that_ you have tried yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two interpretations come to mind.

Interpretation 1: It's the combination of "Date" + "Time" that matters, not the consecutive repetition. In this case, just use `aggregate` (or your favorite aggregating function or package, like "data.table").

```
aggregate(value ~ Date + Time, mydf, median)
#    Date Time value
# 1     A    1   4.5
# 2     B    1   6.0
# 3     A    2   4.0
# 4     B    2   4.0
# 5     A    3   3.0
# 6     B    3   2.0
# 7     A    4   2.0
# 8     A    5   7.0
# 9     B    5   3.0
# 10    B    6   4.0
```

Interpretation 2: The consecutive repetitions *are* important. In this case, you need another "grouping" variable. For this, we can use `rle`. After that, the aggregation step is pretty much the same.

```
RLE <- rle(DF$Time)$lengths
RLE <- rep(seq_along(RLE), RLE)
aggregate(value ~ Date + Time + RLE, DF, median)
#    Date Time RLE value
# 1     A    1   1   4.5
# 2     A    2   2   4.0
# 3     A    3   3   3.0
# 4     A    4   4   2.0
# 5     A    5   5   7.0
# 6     B    1   6   6.0
# 7     B    2   7   4.0
# 8     B    3   8   2.0
# 9     B    5   9   3.0
# 10    B    6  10   4.0
# 11    A    1  11   3.0
# 12    B    3  12   2.0
```

---

For the benefit of others, here's some reproducible data: `mydf` and `DF`. (`DF` is just `mydf` with a few rows repeated.)

```
mydf <- structure(list(Date = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
        "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Time = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), value = c(3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 
        5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("Date", "Time", "value"), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
DF <- rbind(mydf, mydf[c(1, 1, 11, 11), ])
```

Comment: You put some extra assumptions that this was to be done in groups Date  in that solution, but I suspect they were warranted and it certainly simplified the problem.